# Why won't wp_enqueue_scripts work on one site but it will another?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a pretty basic plugin and I've tested it a local site (running through MAMP) and on a live site. When I install the plugin on the actual site I'm using it on the script intended for the user side doesn't doesn't get loaded. All the backend code used in wp-admin works fine but the user `js` file doesn't even load on the site. However, it does on others:

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "headerPromoTxt_user_scripts");

    function headerPromoTxt_user_scripts(){

        wp_register_script('headerPromoTxt_user',plugins_url('/js/header-promo-txt-user.js', __FILE__ ),array('jquery'),'',true);
        wp_enqueue_script('headerPromoTxt_user');

        wp_localize_script('headerPromoTxt_user', 'myAjax', array('ajaxurl'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
        wp_enqueue_script('headerPromoTxt_user');
    }
```

I've turned on debugging and I don't get any errors for the code. I've also just tried doing an `echo "test"` to see if the function is even ran and I get nothing. It's almost like the theme is ignoring the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

Comment: do you see the `<script src="..."></script>` being added in the page source? what does the browser console say? I'd guess its in issue with the path perhaps your local copy is at `/site/` where the live is at `/`

Comment: no `<script src="..."></script>` and no errors in the console. I thought maybe it was a missing file but if I go directly to the file url it's there.

Comment: I did just find that `wp_footer()` and `wp_header()` are missing in that theme. Adding them didn't fix anything though...

Comment: oops! `wp_head()` not `wp_header()`. Adding that to the header.php fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

the problem wasn't the code. The theme was missing the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` functions.